# SonarQube: Error found on uncommitted files

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 6.2 and I set the Leak Period to "previous_version". However, during analysis, SonarQube detects error in files that were not detected in the previous analysis and in which  there was no commit made in the current analysis.

Is this a bug or an issue with my configuration?

Comment: Could you please share with us the logs that contains the errors ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this is not a system error. They are issues detected in the uncommitted files

Comment: What kind of new errors were reported in these files?

Comment: Critical errors

Comment: To clarify: you're seeing new issues raised in code on which there have been no changes? Have you upgraded your analyzer (the language plugin) lately?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes. I am using the latest version of Java Analyzer v4.6.0.8784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By updating the Java analyzer, new issues are detected on files that were not modified. We're aware of the problem. It's fixed in SonarQube 6.3 with [SONAR-8736](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8736)